# Cannot open database "\'name\': \'master\'" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyodbc

I am currently running into the error

> Cannot open database "'name': 'master'" requested by the login. The login failed

when I try and execute my PrintCSV view function in a Django/Python web app

The function is supposed to read through each database on the server and print all the accounts that are in areas.

I am unsure whether this problem might be with my login privileges or with my code itself.

**Views.py:**

```
def PrintCSV(request):
    #Getting list of DB Names
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                          'SERVER=serverIP;'
                          'PORT=port;'
                          'UID=kyle_dev_ro;'
                          'PWD=password;')

    databaseName = 'SELECT name FROM sys.databases'

    cursor = cnxn.cursor();
    cursor.execute(databaseName);
    XdatabaseNames = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    dbNames= []
    for row in XdatabaseNames:
        rdict = {}
        rdict["name"] = row[0]
        dbNames.append(rdict)

    #Starting CSV
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Avonlea_file.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Unit', 'Balance'
                     ])

    for x in dbNames:
        connect = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                                 'SERVER=192.168.1.1;'
                                 'PORT=1433;'
                                 'Database=' + str(x) + ';'
                                 'UID=kyle_dev_ro;'
                                 'PWD=fh$sa#8d#7F8Y3;')

        XaccAreas = " SELECT Account, DCBalance FROM [dbo].[Client] where iAgeingTermID = '3' AND DCBalance < 0 "
        cursor = cnxn.cursor();
        cursor.execute(XaccAreas);
        accAreas = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        for z in accAreas:
            rdict = {}
            rdict["Account"] = z[0]
            rdict["Balance"] = z[1]
            writer.writerow([
                '',
                x,
                '',
            ])
            writer.writerow([
                rdict[0],
                rdict[1],
            ])

    return response
```

**Full Error:**

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Cannot open database "'name': 'master'" requested by the
> login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000]
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
> (0); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot
> open database "'name': 'master'" requested by the login. The login
> failed. (4060); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid
> connection string attribute (0)')

When I had set up the login on Microsoft SQL Studio I had ensured that all the "Mapping" databases that were needed to be ticked, were ticked and that my default database was set to "master"

So I am unsure whether this error originates from the privileges I have given this login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made two mistakes:

- `'Database=' + str(x) + ';'` should be `'Database=' + str(x["name"]) + ';'` because you need to get a particular column, not the whole row
- You probably want to filter out system databases from your query anyway

```
select name
from sys.databases
where database_id > 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this does make sense - However, when I run this code it returns the following --- KeyError at /PrintCSV Exception Value: 1

Comment: Sorry looking at your code I think you need `x["name"]` I missed the fact you are copying into a hash table and then into a list. I'm not that familiar with Python so I may have misread